# Prediction Using Mixed Effects Model

Tags: regression, mixed-model

This is more of a conceptual question, but let me know if more details are needed. Say I am predicting test score and my explanatory variables are subject and study time. I can easily create a linear model of the form:

$score \sim subject + studytime$

However, I know that there are some random effects caused by the actual test-taker. So I can create a mixed effects model of the form:

$score \sim subject + studytime + (1|name)$

I have 2 questions:

1) Can I do prediction on new datasets with people not in the modelling dataset? For example, Jim, Jack and John were used to model, can I predict the testscores for Jennifer or June?

2) If I am using name as the random effect, am I allowed to model also using name specific variables? For example, age of the person, or height of the person?

Comment: 1 ) As subject is set as a fixed effect, there is no way to predict the score of a new subject. Instead, you can set subject as a random effect. By doing that, you acknowledge that there is subject-to-subject variability and the model will estimate this variability. Predicting the score of a new subject then starts by first generating a new random effect from the subject population.

Answer (score 1):

just a few quick thoughts,

1) The training and testing data would need to have the same names. This is because the model won't be able to infer behaviour for data it has not seen before. It relies on quantifying observed relationships and predicting using these.

2) I think this would be fine. You are capturing some individual specific effect in the name in addition to whatever is explained by their age etc

It occurs to me that by grouping using name, you are implying that all persons called John have something in common that determines their final scores. If that is the point, then that's fine.